# Python Try-Except: Why does it not catch it?

Tags: python, try-except

I am trying to get the hang of try/ except and I just can't seem to get it working. I want it to stop for a negative or a very larger number:

```
try:
    h > 0.
except:
    return "Your distance (", h, ") is negative"
try:
    h < 3700000.
except:
    return "Your distance (", h, ") is outside the range this model"
else:
    # Return Correct Value:
    return g0*(r/(r+h))**2
```

Yet it keeps on going to the end no matter what value I throw at it... I've tried different things after except like false and other stuff, but none of them work:

```
>>> print(earth_gravity(1))
1.0
9.80649692152011
>>> print(earth_gravity(-1))
-1.0
9.806503078481338
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because no exception is raised. Use an `if` statement to check the trueness of the condition instead.

```
if h > 0:
   ...
elif ...:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

Comment: So try/except is strictly for errors coming from the language in that sense (and should not be used in this context)?

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot: From exceptional circumstances in the code. A simple comparison isn't exceptional.